# Day/Month/Year doesn't display without hours

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, date

```
string date = Convert.ToString(context.SP_GetDate().FirstOrDefault().UpdateTime);
```

`UpdateTime` is Day/Month/Year in my database however,

When i use above query , update time always displays like below

```
7.1.2014 00:00:00
```

How can i **get day/month/year** ?

Comment: What is the type (or format) of `.UpdateTime`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
string date = context.SP_GetDate().FirstOrDefault().UpdateTime.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy");
```

Comment: I strongly suspect the `Convert.ToDateTime` part isn't required, and currently you're formatting the *minutes* rather than the month...

Comment: This answer is very simple but best!

Answer (score 7):

Specify a format string when performing the conversion. Don't `Convert.ToString`, which doesn't allow for different format strings - call `ToString` on the `DateTime`. For example:

```
DateTime updated = context.SP_GetDate().FirstOrDefault().UpdateTime;
string updatedText = updated.ToString("d");
```

Here, `d` is the "short date" [standard date/time format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). There are others to choose from.

Alternatively, you could specify a [custom date/time format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), e.g.

```
DateTime updated = context.SP_GetDate().FirstOrDefault().UpdateTime;
string updatedText = updated.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Note that these will use the "current culture" for localization, picking the language, standard date format, month names etc. You can specify a different culture if you need to - typically the invariant culture, used for machine to machine communication:

```
DateTime updated = context.SP_GetDate().FirstOrDefault().UpdateTime;
string updatedText = updated.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 4):

`Convert.ToString()` is a generic conversion, simple but inflexible.

[DateTime.ToString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.DateTime.ToString%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) gives you lots of option, including [custom formatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and overriding the default locale.